# Nail Color Change from hand in Android Studio (JAVA)

Tags: java, python, android

Look at the First Image i want to detect the nails from hand and change the color of the nails as shown in the second Image, i want to create the nail color change app in android studio

https://i.stack.imgur.com/meAmy.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JtMp.jpg

Comment: wasnt this asked yesterday lol...

Comment: I don't know do u have any idea how to do this

Comment: you have asked similar question under another user yesterday, didn't you?

Comment: Google sceneform has some limitations in some devices so do u have any better solution for this

Comment: Go with opencv. detect your object and change their colors.

Comment: Do you have any reference how to do this using opencv